# 'where' operator: Failed to resolve table or column or scalar expression named

Tags: kql, microsoft365-defender

For a Query in Microsoft Defender Advanced Hunting I want to use Data from an external Table (here  the KQL_Test_Data.csv) but when I try to run it I get the Error message:

> 'where' operator: Failed to resolve table or column or scalar expression named 'IOC'

and when i highlight the whole Query as told in ['where' operator: failed to resolve scalar expression named 'timeOffsetMin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69165660/where-operator-failed-to-resolve-scalar-expression-named-timeoffsetmin) i get this error message:

> No tabular expression statement found

This is the code i used:

```
let IOC = externaldata(column:string) 
[   
h@"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kornuptiko/TEMP/main/KQL_Test_Data.csv" 
] 
with(format="csv");

DeviceNetworkEvents 
| where Timestamp > ago(30d) 
| where RemoteIP in (IOC);
```

Comment: Does `externaldata` works for you by its own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming microsoft365-defender supports `externaldata`:

Your file is not a valid CSV, and [KQL is strict about this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingestion-supported-formats).
As a work-around we can read the file as `txt` and then parse it.

```
let IOC = externaldata(column:string) 
[   
    h@"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kornuptiko/TEMP/main/KQL_Test_Data.csv" 
] 
with(format="txt")
| parse column with * '"' ip '"' *
| project ip;
DeviceNetworkEvents 
| where Timestamp > ago(30d) 
| where RemoteIP in (IOC);
```

Comment: That works thanks! Now i only have to add authentication for sharepoint since GitHub was only to test is...